# Programmatically running JavaScript with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I need to programmatically (in Java) run JavaScript with Node.js and read the error. There are two approach:

1. call `node -e <javascript>`
2. Save the JavaScript to a temp file, and call `node temp.js`

How are they different?

It seems that the first approach is more efficient, but when I run something like

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    console.error(typeof(err));
});
function x_5(x_6, x_7) {
  var x_8 = Infinity;
}
throw x_5;
```

It prints

```
[eval]:8
throw x_5;
      ^
function
```

But all I wanted was just the last line. The second approach only gave me the last line. So I am trying to understand how the two approaches are different, and how I can get rid of the unnecessary error message.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html

Comment: More details? Note that I am using Java to call `node` command to run JavaScript

Comment: Then why don't you provide those details from the beginning instead of letting us guess?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a known bug in node < v0.11.9, you may have to upgrade node. See here https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/572

Comment: My node version is 0.11.10-pre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you see `node -e script` will dump exception to stderr, so you can print the result to stdout.

**console.log instead of console.error**

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    console.log(typeof(err));
});
```

**on java side, take result from stdout, ignore stderr**

```
String[] command = {"node", "-e", js};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
for (int i = 0; i < in.available(); i++) {
    System.out.println("" + in.read());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited your Java side code so that things in the JS code could be escaped automatically.